# WordPress website is not able to access to URL since the modification of permalinks

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, permalinks

I'm working on a Wordpress website and I was looking for having a permalink with the name of the publication of my articles. I selected on the permalink option "Name of the publication". Since this modification, I'm not able to access to the different pages / articles on my website.

I know that problem can occur when we don't have the mod_rewrite loaded. I created an info.php and I saw in the list of the Loaded Modules "mod_rewrite". I also tried to modify the htaccess file and it still not working.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Do you have an idea? 
Thank you

Comment: Not sure if it applies to you, but the web host for one of my websites requires the .htaccess to be regenerated via the hosting account manager as well when I make changes to the wordpress permalink structure.

Comment: It's not working, but thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Create a backup of your .htaccess (.zip it) then, delete your .htaccess. After deleting, click save permalink.